# Is dYSM file required for Android in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

This is a general question. Is dYSM file required for android ecosystem?
Considering all platform such as AndroidTV and Devices.

Any Help?

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
```

```
"com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dSYM files are specific Apple's developer tools, and they contain debug symbols that allow Crashlytics to convert the address information it finds in the stack trace of a crash back to the symbols in your code.

Builds on Android may generate similar debug symbol files, for example when you use a tool like ProGuard or R8 to minify your build output. Crashlytics uploads those files automatically during the build when `firebaseCrashlytics.mappingFileUploadEnabled` is set to `true` (its default), so you shouldn't have have to do to make Crashlytics work with these files.

For more, check out the documentation on [getting readable crash reports in the Crashlytics dashboard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android) and [required configuration when using R8, ProGuard, and DexGuard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android#config-r8-proguard-dexguard).